# How to keep application work when executing button click java

Tags: java, yahoo

When I click the check button, the application stops while processing the job.

I want to get a real time result.

This is my code.

I check some yahoo accounts with this application.

When I click check I want to get results one by one, but when I click check I must wait till all the accounts are checked, and then I get the result.

```
package package_1;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import package_1.ProgressBarDemo2.Task;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class EmailChecker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    public static boolean state = true;
    public Task task;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        EmailChecker window = new EmailChecker();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public void checkcurrent(String[] _Account,String[] _Pass,JTextArea _textArea,JTextArea _textArea_1,int _i,JProgressBar _progressBar,int _size) throws InterruptedException{

        if(_i<_size && state == true){

            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.debug", "false");
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            try {
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                try {
                    store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", _Account[_i], _Pass[_i]);
                } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                }
                if(store.isConnected() == true){
                    _textArea.setText(_Account[_i]+"/"+_Pass[_i]+ "\n" + _textArea.getText() );
                }else{

                    _textArea_1.setText(_Account[_i]+"/"+_Pass[_i] + "\n" +_textArea_1.getText());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            _progressBar.setValue(100);
            _i++;
            System.out.println("checked");
            checkcurrent(_Account,_Pass,_textArea,_textArea_1,_i,_progressBar,_size);
        }else{
            state = false;
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public EmailChecker() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 655, 433);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(10, 34, 100, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane);

        JTextPane textPane_1 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_1.setBounds(120, 34, 92, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane_1);

        JTextPane textPane_2 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_2.setBounds(332, 34, 92, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane_2);

        JTextPane textPane_3 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_3.setBounds(222, 34, 100, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane_3);

        JTextPane textPane_4 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_4.setBounds(544, 34, 92, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane_4);

        JTextPane textPane_5 = new JTextPane();
        textPane_5.setBounds(434, 34, 100, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textPane_5);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setToolTipText("Account Ok");
        textArea.setBounds(10, 222, 292, 154);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setMinimum(100);
        progressBar.setBounds(10, 379, 626, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar);

        JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
        textArea_1.setBounds(344, 222, 292, 154);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_1);

        JButton btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
        btnCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    String[] Account = textPane.getText().split("\\n");
                    String[] Pass = textPane_1.getText().split("\\n");
                    //String[] Proxy = textPane_2.getText().split("\\n");
                    //String[] Port = textPane_3.getText().split("\\n");
                    //String[] Login = textPane_4.getText().split("\\n");
                    //String[] PassPrx = textPane_5.getText().split("\\n");

                    int size = Account.length;
                    int i = 0;

                    try {
                        checkcurrent(Account,Pass,textArea,textArea_1,i,progressBar,size);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        btnCheck.setLocation(280, 185);
        btnCheck.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnCheck.setSize(83, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCheck);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        return null;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: You have do make your application run asynchronuously, in order to have a non-blocking UI, for example, by running your `checkcurrent()` method in a new `Thread`.

Here's a tutorial on multi-threading in Java: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/multithreading-in-java/

Comment: thanks im new java coder can you modify my code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AsysncTask.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
>
> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.
>
> An asynchronous task is defined by a computation that runs on a
>   background thread and whose result is published on the UI thread. An
>   asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params,
>   Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground,
>   onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Here's a nice way to visualize asynctask:

[image] (blog.fabgate.co)

Basically, you have a long task. Running it in the UI thread will block up the UI, and possibly cause your app to crash. But, if you use Aysync task, you can do it in a separate thread, while displaying a progress bar or percentage done by using the onProgressUpdate() method.

Here's an example to download a file from AsyncTask, and give info. to the main UI thread about the progress:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

urls is an array with the URL's that the user requested to download. A simple for loop loops through every requested URL, and publishes the progress using the `onProgressUpdate` method, in order to show the user their task is being done.

EDIT:

For you, I think you should put this code:

```
try {
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                try {
                    store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", _Account[_i], _Pass[_i]);
                } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                }
                if(store.isConnected() == true){
                    _textArea.setText(_Account[_i]+"/"+_Pass[_i]+ "\n" + _textArea.getText() );
                }else{

                    _textArea_1.setText(_Account[_i]+"/"+_Pass[_i] + "\n" +_textArea_1.getText());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

into async task. Like this. You want to do it in the background, so it goes in the `doInBackground` method:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 

  try {
                Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
                try {
                    store.connect("imap.mail.yahoo.com", _Account[_i], _Pass[_i]);
                } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
                }
                if(store.isConnected() == true){
                    _textArea.setText(_Account[_i]+"/"+_Pass[_i]+ "\n" + _textArea.getText() );
                }else{

                    _textArea_1.setText(_Account[_i]+"/"+_Pass[_i] + "\n" +_textArea_1.getText());

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

And set your progress bar in onProgressUpdate() method. That runs on the main thread, so you can set progress bars right from that method itself.

Let me know if this helped,

Ruchir

Comment: thanks this what i need, can you modify my code im new in java :(

Comment: i dont know how to implement this code in my project

Comment: @hakimRasfi Okay, I have edited my answer with your code. Please like if useful! Let me know

Comment: Sorry i cant rightnow look --> Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: Thats alright, I'm just glad I helped! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: there are no friend zone in stackoverflow ?

Comment: by the way i used your method in addition to SwingWorker and it worked perfectly

Comment: @hakimRasfi You used SwingWorker in android?

Comment: @hakimRasfi I thought that was only for pure java, not android?

Comment: no this is not android application its windows application

Comment: @hakimRasfi Oh really? I don't know much about windows phones, how can the same android classes work?

Comment: its just a windows desktop application bro not windows phone

Comment: yeah pure java im c#/php/html/css/jquery/javascript/mysql/sqlserver developer  im beginner in java and i used a pure java

Comment: you are android developer ?

Comment: @hakimRasfi Yeah, android and java.

Comment: @hakimRasfi If you have any android devices, you can download one of my games: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.CurlyBrace.ruchir.TileTap&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT